# ¿Cómo convertir un GIF animado a WEBP animado?

Tags: php, gd

Estoy usando [GD](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) para manipular imágenes en PHP, basado [este código](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromgif.php#104473)

```
<?php
/**
Función para detectar si una imagen es animación
*/
function is_ani($filename) {  
    if(!($fh = @fopen($filename, 'rb')))
        return false;
    $count = 0;
    while(!feof($fh) && $count < 2) {
        $chunk = fread($fh, 1024 * 100);
        $count += preg_match_all('#\x00\x21\xF9\x04.{4}\x00(\x2C|\x21)#s', $chunk, $matches);
   }

    fclose($fh);
    return $count > 1;
}
?>
```

pretendo separar los frames dentro del GIF (puedo incluso usar [esta librería](https://github.com/Sybio/GifFrameExtractor)) y salvarlos en formato [WEBP](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.imagewebp.php).

¿Cómo puedo ensamblar/crear una imagen animada en formato WEBP usando GD en PHP?

**--EDITADO--**

Versión de PHP:

```
PHP 7.2.4 (built: Apr 25 2018 12:05:18) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.2.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
```

gd_info:

```
#php -r 'print_r(gd_info());'
Array
(
    [GD Version] => bundled (2.1.0 compatible)
    [FreeType Support] =>
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPEG Support] => 1
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] =>
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [WebP Support] => 1
    [BMP Support] => 1
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] =>
)
```

Este sistema está corriendo en Debian 8.

**--EDITADO 2--**

Usando como base el [proyecto de alo-malbarez](https://github.com/aloMalbarez/php-GD-Animated-webp) y una clase para extraer los frames de los GIF's hice un **[proyecto](https://github.com/SolracLeinad/php-GD-Animated-webp)** con una clase extractora mas limpia y clara para las personas que necesiten fragmentos específicos del GIF. En este proyecto junto ambas clases para hacer un convertidor de GIF a WEBP, todavía tiene fallos pero trabajo en corregirlas.

Comment: agrega la información a tu pregunta en caso de que los enlaces dejen de funcionar, saludos!

Comment: mira este [enlace](https://cloudinary.com/blog/animated_webp_how_to_convert_animated_gif_to_webp_and_save_up_to_90_bandwidth)

Comment: Gracias @SebastiánLagosYañez pero quisiera hacerlo solamente con PHP y la librería GD. Por ejemplo, para cambiar el tamaño de un GIF animado hay que sacar cada frame de ese GIF, cambiar el tamaño y volver a armar el GIF.  Me imagino que lo mismo aplica para webp solo que debería haber ciertos headers para cada frame, supongo.

Comment: Buenas @Solrac, tiene que ser con GD? A ver si [este](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromwebp.php) te sirve

Comment: y esto te sirve [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2569970/gd-converting-a-png-image-to-jpeg-and-making-the-alpha-by-default-white-and-not)

Comment: Gracias @msabate la función `imagecreatefromwebp()` es para crear un objeto imagen a partir de una imagen `webp`. También es parte de la librería GD. Lo que no quiero es usar librerías o programas externos porque mi ambiente PHP está dentro de un *chroot*

Comment: Gracias @SebastiánLagosYañez pero eso es para cambiar el color de la capa de transparencia de una imagen PNG.

Comment: ¿Qué versión de php tienes? ¿qué devuelve var_dump(gd_info());? ambas respuestas a estas preguntas deberías incluirlas en la pregunta para facilitarnos el trabajo.

Comment: Hola @track3r edité mi pregunta para incluir la info solicitada aunque no debería hacer mucha diferencia. Es decir, puedo guardar archivos Webp sin problema y convertir imágenes estáticas de un formato a otro. La cuestión en específico son los GIF animados.

Comment: Gracias, solo quería asegurarme de que **[WebP Support] => 1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faltaría el tema de como extraes los frames del gif, pero para eso hay un link al final

Aqui va una PdC de como armar un webp animado en php usando sólo GD (con soporte webp)

PARTE 1 : encodear cada frame

1) el frame se convierte a webp con GD y se captura en una variable con `ob_start`

2) descartamos el header de fileformat de este stream y guardamos el frameData (empieza con "VP8 " y va hasta el final) en un array (buffer) junto a la info de ancho, alto y duración del frame

3) vuelve a 1 hasta que no hay mas frames

**nota:**
para cambiarle la calidad de compresión editar la línea

```
imagewebp($image);
```

poniendo por ejemplo

```
imagewebp($image, null, 75);
```

el `null` es para que no grabe un archivo

PARTE 2 : armar el webp animado segun la especificación
https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/riff_container

> An animated image with EXIF metadata may look as follows:
>
> RIFF/WEBP

```
+- VP8X (descriptions of features used)
+- ANIM (global animation parameters)
+- ANMF (frame1 parameters + data)
+- ANMF (frame2 parameters + data)
+- ANMF (frame3 parameters + data)
+- ANMF (frame4 parameters + data)
+- EXIF (metadata) <- opcional
```

0) open stream o armar en una var

1) header fileformat (RIFF+filesize+WEBP)

1.a) calcular el filesize (uint32) 
el filesize es el total de bytes del archivo -8 del header, ó el total de bytes de todos los chunks + 4

2) chunk header VP8X

2.a) calcular chunksize (uint32) = 10

2.b) poner los bits de alpha y animacion a 1

2.c) codificar ancho y alto del canvas en uint24 (-1)

3) chunk header ANIM

3.a) calcular chunksize (uint32) = 6

3.b) color de fondo: BGRA (0,0,0,0)

3.c) loop count (uint16) 0=infinityandbeyond

4) por cada frame guardado en el array (buffer) PARTE 1.2

4.a) chunk header ANMF

4.b) calcular chunksize (uint32) = 16 + total de bytes en frameData

4.c) origen X,Y del frame (uint24) (/2)

4.d) ancho y alto del frame (uint24) (-1)

4.e) duración milisegundos (uint24)

4.f) reserved (6 bits) + alpha blending (1 bit) + descartar frame (1 bit)

4.g) el frame Data guardado en el buffer PARTE 1.2

5) save to disk o close stream

```
#!/usr/bin/env php
<?php

function toUint32($n){
  $ar = unpack("C*", pack("L", $n));
  return $ar;
}
function toUint24($n){
  $ar = unpack("C*", pack("L", $n));
  array_pop($ar);
  return $ar;
}
function toUint16($n){
  $ar = unpack("C*", pack("S", $n));
  return $ar;
}

function bytesToString($bytes){
  return implode(array_map("chr", $bytes));
}

function binaryToBytes($bits){
  $octets = explode(' ', $bits);
  return array_map("bindec", $octets);
}

$oWidth=120;
$oHeight=20;

$frameArray = [];

function getFrameData($image, $msec){
  $w = imagesx($image);
  $h = imagesy($image);

  ob_start();
  imagewebp($image);
  if (ob_get_length() % 2 == 1) :
    echo "\0";
  endif;
  $image_data = ob_get_contents();
  ob_end_clean();
  $frameData = substr($image_data, strpos($image_data, "VP8 "));
  return Array(
    "frameData" => $frameData,
    "duration" => bytesToString(toUint24($msec)),
    "width" => bytesToString(toUint24($w - 1)),
    "height" => bytesToString(toUint24($h -1 )),
  );
}

// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($oWidth, $oHeight);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 233, 14, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'WebP with PHP', $text_color);

$frameArray[] = getFrameData($im, 70);
imagedestroy($im);

// Create a blank image and add some text
$im = imagecreatetruecolor($oWidth, $oHeight);
$text_color = imagecolorallocate($im, 14, 233, 91);
imagestring($im, 1, 5, 5,  'WebP with PHP', $text_color);

$frameArray[] = getFrameData($im, 70);
imagedestroy($im);

// create new WEBP
$fileWEBP = "";
$fileHeader = "";
$fileContents = "";

// Chunk HEADER VP8X
$fileContents .="VP8X";
$headChunkSize = bytesToString(toUint32(10));
// bit flags Rsv|I|L|E|X|A|R|                   Reserved
$oVP8XflagsBin = "00010010 00000000 00000000 00000000";
$oVP8Xflags = bytesToString(binaryToBytes($oVP8XflagsBin));
$oCanvasSize = bytesToString(toUint24($oWidth-1)).bytesToString(toUint24($oHeight-1));
$fileContents .= $headChunkSize. $oVP8Xflags. $oCanvasSize;

// Chunk HEADER ANIM
$fileContents .="ANIM";
$animChunkSize = bytesToString(toUint32(6));
// loop count 16bits, 0 = infinito
// bytesToString(toUint16(0));
$oLoopCount = str_repeat(chr(0), 2);
// 32bits BGRA, Blue Green Red Alpha (0,0,0,0)
$oBackGround = str_repeat(chr(0), 4);
$fileContents .= $animChunkSize . $oBackGround . $oLoopCount;

foreach ($frameArray as $frame) :
  // Chunk HEADER ANMF
  $fileContents .="ANMF";
  $frameDataChunkSize = bytesToString(toUint32(strlen($frame['frameData'])+16));
  // frame origin X Y
  // bytesToString(toUint24(originX)) . bytesToString(toUint24(originY))
  // (0,0)
  $fOrigin = str_repeat(chr(0), 6);
  // frame size (uint24) width-1 , (uint24) height-1
  $fSize = $frame['width'].$frame['height'];
  // frame duration in miliseconds (uint24)
  $fDuration = $frame['duration'];
  // frame options bits
  // reserved (6 bits) + alpha blending (1 bit) + descartar frame (1 bit)
  $fFlagsBin = "00000010";
  $fFlags = bytesToString(binaryToBytes($fFlagsBin));
  // chunk payload
  $fileContents .= $frameDataChunkSize.$fOrigin.$fSize.$fDuration.$fFlags.$frame['frameData'];
endforeach;

// calculate Size and build file header
$fileSize = bytesToString(toUint32(strlen($fileContents)+4));
$fileHeader = "RIFF".$fileSize."WEBP";
$fileWEBP = $fileHeader.$fileContents;

file_put_contents('animated.webp',$fileWEBP);
```

link del repo por si queres extenderlo o hacer un fork con la parte de extraer los gif frames

https://github.com/aloMalbarez/php-GD-Animated-webp

para extraer los frames del gif podes usar esta clase

https://github.com/jacoka/GIFDecoder

onda `foreach ( $gifDecoder -> GIFGetFrames ( ) as $frame )`

**Edit** puse link a la clase GIFDecoder del autor original

Comment: Definitivamente la dirección correcta, estoy adaptando todo para que funcione en conjunto y transforme el GIF en WEBP animado. Compartiré el resultado cuando lo tenga en perfecto estado. Gracias @alo-malbarez

Comment: Tengo problemas con las animaciones que tienen transparencia, en concreto las que solamente mueven `sprites` sobre una imagen de fondo. Al extraer los frames y salvarlos en `webp` o `gif` todo se ve perfecto, pero al ponerlos todos juntos en una animación webp el resultado son zonas negras en donde alguna vez hubo un `sprite`. He intentado modificando el `alpha blending` y `disposal method` pero no resuelve nada. ¿Alguna sugerencia antes de abrir una nueva pregunta?

Comment: un frame gif a webp sale con transparencia? es decir el chunk "VP8 " incluye el canal alpha?

Comment: habría que probar localmente generar un webp animado con `convert` de `imageMagick` y comparar con un editor hexadecimal a ver donde están las diferencias (usar imágenes pequeñas y 2 o 3 frames para no perderse en la maraña de bytes), por lo que sé el convertidor oficial `webpmux` no soporta frames "VP8 " (estuve un buen rato tratando de validar el webp generado hasta q lo leí en un foro)

Comment: Los frames individuales contienen el subchunk "ALPH", logré solucionar parcialmente esto modificando `$frameData = substr($image_data, strpos($image_data, "VP8 "));` por una condicional que busca "ALPH" primero, de encontrarlo `$frameData` iniciará ahí. Funciona pero la calidad del webp animado tiene mucha basura. Intenté modificar los bits `Rsv| P | F | C |` del subchunk "ALPH" de cada frame pero seguramente algo estoy haciendo mal.

Comment: en cuanto pueda lo veo, por lo pronto se me ocurre que la compresion con pérdida estaría generando artifacts y polucionando pixels que deberían ser transparentes, poniendo a 100 el quality mejora?

Comment: No encontré diferencia además de la obvia. He hecho un Fork de tu repo en GIT para no contaminarlo. Tengo 2 clases juntas para extraer el GIF y para ensamblar el WEBP en [este repo](https://github.com/SolracLeinad/php-GD-Animated-webp)

Answer (score 0):

Realmente existe poca información, me ha costado encontrar esto:

https://gauntface.com/blog/2014/09/02/webp-support-with-imagemagick-and-php

También existen ejemplos en la documentación oficial por parte de PHP:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagewebp.php
http://php.net/manual/es/function.imagecreatefromgif.php

Pero te resumo el primer enlace (que es el interesante) para tu caso en particular:

```
<?php
    $im = imagecreatefromgif($filepath);
    imagewebp($im, $resizedFilepath);
    imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Después tienes la posibilidad de usar un comando tipo shell con un binario del tipo: https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/docs/gif2webp

Aunque te advierto que el formato está poco soportado y no sé hasta qué punto es fiable, según he ido investigando, diría que está en una fase muy verde del desarrollo.